# Angular 9 : Error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'url' of class 'DataService'. Found string

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

While working on a program that I am facing an issue with, constructor and its dependency injection from its child class.

- *DataService*: A service class which has all the CRUD operation at one place and also has a parameterized constructor for injecting the end-point URL and HTTP from its child classes.

```
constructor(private url: string, private http: Http) { }
```

- *PostService* : A service class which extends the above DataService class to have the CRUD operation functionality within it and a one-parameterized constructor and internally calls the super(endPointURL, httpObject) as below :

```
constructor(http: Http) {
    super('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', http);
}
```

Before this re-factoring (moving all the common CRUD operation and extending it by child classes) my code was working as expected but **AFTER** the above changes I am getting the below error:

```
Date: 2020-03-22T15:26:23.248Z - Hash: 7130497a38c152c58258
5 unchanged chunks

Time: 1859ms

ERROR in src/app/services/data.service.ts:14:23 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'url' of class 'DataService'.
Found string

14   constructor(private url: string, private http: Http) { }
```

Also, when I remove the *url* param from Datsource constructor (modify PostService.ts accordingly) the api is working as expected. *Not sure why !!!*

I am using:

Angular CLI: 9.0.4
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

### Package                      Version

@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.4

@angular-devkit/core         9.0.4

@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.4

@schematics/angular          9.0.4

@schematics/update           0.900.4

rxjs                         6.5.3

***DataService.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppError } from '../common/app-error';
import { NotFoundError } from '../common/not-found-error';
import { BadInput } from '../common/bad-input';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

//   private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private url: string, private http: Http) { }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandle));
  } 

  create(resource) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(resource))
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandle));
  }

  update(resource) {
    return this.http.patch(this.url + '/' + resource.id, JSON.stringify({ isRead: true }))
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandle));
  }

  delete(resource) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + resource.id)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandle));
  }
  
  private errorHandle(error: Response){
    if (error.status === 404) {
      return throwError(new NotFoundError());
    }
    if (error.status === 400) {
      return throwError(new BadInput(error.json()));
    }
    return throwError(new AppError(error));
  }

}
```

***PostService.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable()
export class PostService extends DataService {

  constructor(http: Http) {
    super('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', http);
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure what's the problem, but for sure you should use the "new" Http: `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: @developer033, Thanks for the quick reply but as I told, I have just starting learning Angular and have been following as per the Udemy session example. Please do let me know if you think I can take some other approach. And thanks for editing !

Comment: [take a look at this sample using **`HttpClient`**](https://ng-run.com/edit/wg9x5IGTH7kGsC9Y4UV4)

Comment: @developer033, Nahh. It didn't work. Still the same error in console.

Comment: could you reproduce it in the demo I provided?

Comment: Sorry was not able to reproduce it.

But it worked after removing @Injectable() from DataService.ts, not sure why !

Comment: Restarting my editor fixed the issue for me, it was a glitch for me.

Answer (score 60):

In **DataService.ts** :

Update the Constructor.

```
//import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(String) private url: string, private http: Http)
```

***UPDATED (Explanation):***

According to https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/di/angular2/inject_and_injectable ;

`@Inject()` is a manual mechanism for letting Angular know that a parameter must be injected.

`@Inject` decorator is only needed for injecting primitives.

***The primitive types*** are number, string, boolean, bigint, symbol, null, undefined.

**The other (**alternative**) way can be used is:**

```
//import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Inject('url') private url: string;
```

Comment: Hey @Useme, Thankyou for the suggestion but wants to know any specific reason for injecting String explicitly ? And that too not 'string' but injecting 'String' explicitly ?

Also before going through your approach while googling I got to see a solution in which it was asked to remove @Injectable() from DataService.ts, not sure why ! But this also worked for me. :)

Comment: With some kind of explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36418185/2816279 Explanations are useful, for coders.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a class that I need to extend. I also want to inject a service into the child. When I  go to add my service it forces me to use  super. The parent class has an empty variable. I use both solutions you mentioned above and neither worked. I receive an error:
core.js:5980 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AuthModule)[String -> String -> String -> String]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for String!

Answer (score 27):

remove **@Injectable()** from **DataService.ts**

Comment: Yeah It will will, Have mentioned in my previous ansers. BDW, Thanks :) but can you let me know the reason behind that !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452578/how-should-i-extend-injectable-from-another-injectable-with-many-injections-in-a

Answer (score 11):

As I encounter with same error myself, with same notation I believe you've watched 'Mosh' angular course which was belong to version 4.

There were several changes since then, one of them is replacing Http with HttpClient, another one was huge changes in rxjs library, needless to say same happened for services .Now instead of putting your services in providers you use @Injectable method which I think is more cleaner and more related to the service itself.

However if you had close attention to implementation you'll notice that DataService is just a base class and it would never be use as a service itself.It's like a manifest.So, it does not need to be injected or provided in app module. If you can recall 'Mosh' never did provide it in App module.The only service that was provided was PostService. That's why you should remove @Injectable decoration from DataService.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the parameter that throws the error, and all uses of the class. This error is commonly thrown when a **constructor** defines **parameters** with primitive types such as **string**, **number**, **boolean**, and **Object**.

- Use the **@Injectable method** or **@Inject decorator from @angular/core** to
  ensure that the type you are injecting is reified (has a runtime
  representation).
- Instead of using

  ```
    constructor( private url: string, private http: HttpClient) { }
  ```
- Use the below codes.

  ```
    import { Component, Inject, } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

     constructor(@Inject(String) private url: string, private http: HttpClient) 
     { }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For NX MFE and angular 15 currently it also can be caused if you have a **standalone components** structure approach.

In this way, you need to insert your service as a global service to global providers in bootstrap.ts of your mfe app file like:

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes, withEnabledBlockingInitialNavigation()),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule),
    importProvidersFrom(CoreModule),
    YourGloballyInsertedService, // <-- here
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you defined a parameter with a primitive type! Pass your url another way!